# Inserting Blob Data

Tags: rest-api

I am using the SalesForceSharp .NET driver. Does anyone know if there is a way to insert blob data with SalesForceSharp similar to this reference?

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm#multipart_message_considerations

I am trying to insert Chatter files bigger than 38 MB using the API. We already have the REST API enabled to handle file uploads up to 500 MB.

Thanks,

Jay

Comment: Can you provide a link to the "SalesForceSharp .NET driver". A quick Google search only pointed back at this question.

Comment: Sure. https://github.com/giacomelli/SalesforceSharp

Comment: Daniel - Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Using Chatter REST API Inputs - Uploading Binary Files](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/Content/intro_input.htm#cc_upload_binary_files) the file needs to be POSTed in using a multipart/form-data request.

I had a quick look at the [SalesforceSharp.SalesforceClient](https://github.com/giacomelli/SalesforceSharp/blob/master/src/SalesforceSharp/SalesforceClient.cs), which seems to be doing the grunt work of making the API requests. There was nothing in the `Request` method that suggested it could handle a multipart request with an octet-stream.

Also, it appears to be working against the Force.com REST API rather than the Chatter REST API. I'm not sure how interchangeable the two are.

E.g. you need to be posting to something like:

> /services/data/v30.0/chatter/feeds/user-profile/005x0000001T9PwAAK/feed-items

Rather than:

> /services/data/v28.0/feed-items

---

**[Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET](http://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET)**

I'm not sure this will provide the solution either. [ChatterClient](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/blob/8d3335f2b1f569ee21ede7002b99c32bd43d08d5/src/ChatterToolkitForNET/ChatterClient.cs).`PostFeedItemAsync`() calls to [ServiceHttpClient](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/blob/8d3335f2b1f569ee21ede7002b99c32bd43d08d5/src/CommonLibrariesForNET/ServiceHttpClient.cs).HttpPostAsync(). This latter method is only posting the JSON, not a multipart request including the octlet stream. [I'll see if @WadeWegner can advise](https://twitter.com/FishOfPrey/status/454044215412924416) about the support for chatter file uploads.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Daniel.  I discovered those limitations with the driver.  I researched another driver.  Here is a link to it: https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET  It interacts with the Chatter REST API.  This API seems like it might be able to do it.  client.PostFeedItemAsync<T>();  Do you think this might work with multipart requests?

Comment: Yeah, the multi-part request is the main issue.  Appreciate your feedback.  I'm in touch with SalesForce support.  I will let you know if I receive a solid answer.